# Javafx mac terminal external process

Tags: macos, javafx, terminal, external-process

Using JavaFX, I am trying to run a program a.out on Terminal of Mac OSX. The following code does not work on Mac. The same code works on Windows by writing cmndM={"cmd","/c","start","a.exe"}. What's wrong on Mac?

```
protected void onRunClick(ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {
    String exeM="./a.out";
    Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] cmndM= {"/bin/sh","-c",exeM}; Process pm=null; File dirM=new File(pth);
    try {
        pm=runtime.exec(cmndM, null, dirM);}
    }catch (IOException e) {
        msg.setText("Error in running simulation.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to location of the file.

I'd have tried with fixed location first, just to be sure it works.

Also, make sure the file is actually there, inside `pth`.

```
package javafxapplication1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String exeM="/tmp/a.out";
                Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
                String[] cmndM= {"/bin/sh","-c",exeM}; 
                Process pm=null; 
                File dirM=new File("/tmp");
                try {
                    pm=runtime.exec(cmndM, null, dirM);
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code by the suggestion, and a.out ran successfully. But, the Terminal does not appear on the screen. How can I make screen visible?

Comment: You are looking for something like this `open -b com.apple.terminal /tmp/a.out` instead of running `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`

Comment: 'cmndM= {"open","-b","com.apple.terminal"};' could open theTeminal. But 'cmndM= {"open","-b","com.apple.terminal","-c",exeM};' couldn't, and happened nothing. If I use 'cmndM= {"open","-b","com.apple.terminal",exeM};', 'Segmentation fault: 11' occured. I cannnot run a.out on visible Terminal yet.